# What does the pair of vertical lines in empirical entropy formula mean?

Tags: machine-learning, notation

I am learning from this [post.](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4047359/Step-by-Step-Guide-To-Implement-Machine-Learning-2)

$\alpha$ is the ratio of the first subset,

$$\alpha=\frac{\left|D_{1}\right|}{\left|D\right|}$$

according to the context and code of the post, $\left|D\right|$ means the number of samples?

- What are the pair of vertical lines called?

Is it the L1 norm symbol? It does not seem to be the absolute value symbol.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$D$ is a set which is further divided into sets $D_{1}$ and $D_{2}$. In this context the vertical lines represent the cardinality of the set i.e. the number of elements in the set. Hence, $\alpha$ represents the ratio of number of samples of $D_{1}$ to $D$.